# PySpark - Try to use Delta Lake in AWS Glue with saveAsTable

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, delta-lake

I am trying to have an experience with Delta data in AWS Glue. I am creating an AWS Glue job using Glue 4.0 version.

In Job details I added two job parameters:

--conf  Value:spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog

--datalake-formats   Value:delta

The code:

```
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import boto3

from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.storagelevel import StorageLevel
from pyspark.sql.types import *

from delta import *
from delta.tables import *

# Define contexts and setting log level
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
spark = glueContext.spark_session
logger = glueContext.get_logger()
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

# Spark configurations
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")
#spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

job = Job(glueContext)
job.init('delta-lake-exp', args)
glue_client = boto3.client('glue')

EXECUTION_DATE = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
db_name = "test_db"
final_table = "delta_table"


#DUMMY DATA THAT WILL BE REPLACED FOR A DYNAMIC SOURCE
data = [(1,'Lily'),(2,'Manuel'),(3,'Emily')]

schema = StructType([StructField("id",IntegerType(),False),StructField("name",StringType(),True)])

source_df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)

source_df = source_df.withColumn('country', F.lit('UK'))

try:
    response = glue_client.get_table(
        DatabaseName='test_db',
        Name=final_table)
    created_table = True
except:
    created_table = False

## MAIN GOAL HERE IS TO CREATE A FLAG TO GET THE UPDATE ROWS: NC - NOT CHANGED; I- INSERTED; U-UPDATED
source_df = source_df.withColumn('flag', F.lit('NC')).withColumn('modified_at',F.lit(EXECUTION_DATE))

if created_table:
    #not time to develop the merge logic yet
    print('test')
else:
# FIRST EXECUTION ALL ROWS ARE INSERTED
    final_df = source_df.withColumn('flag',F.lit('I'))

db_tab = '`' + f"{db_name}" + '`' + '.' + f"{final_table}"

additional_options = {
    "path": "s3://bucket_test_dl_0065/delta_table/"
}

final_df.repartition(1).write \
    .format("delta") \
    .options(**additional_options) \
    .mode("append") \
    .partitionBy("country") \
    .saveAsTable(db_tab)

job.commit()
```

I followed the AWS page -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format-delta-lake.html

The error is always the same

```
File "/tmp/delta-lake-exp.py", line, in <module>
    .saveAsTable(db_tab)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line, in saveAsTable
    self._jwrite.saveAsTable(name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
```

I already tried to create the table manually before execute the AWS Glue job but the errors keeps the same.

Anyone had the same issue?

Thanks